# Flip values in 2d square array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way for me to do the first method with only one nested for loop, without the first for loop some values did not flip, since you're basically doing the inverse x,y --> y,x and flipping over x=y (since 0,0 is top left) why won't my nested for loop work by itself?

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * ~~~~~~ BONUS ~~~~~~ EXTRA CREDIT ~~~~~~
 * transpose grid (similar to arrayReverse)
 * (i.e. reflect over its main diagonal 
 * (which runs top-left to bottom-right)
 * you MUST call the swap helper method 
 * but you man NOT create a second array for storage
 * example:
 *  1 2 3                 1 4 7
 *  4 5 6   would become  2 5 8
 *  7 8 9                 3 6 9
 * </pre>
 */
public static void gridTranspose() {

    if (gridIsSquare() == true) {
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length / 2 + 1; r++) {
            gridSwap(0, r, r, 0);
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length / 2 + 1; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
                gridSwap(r, c, c, r);

            }

        }
    }
}

/**
 * <pre>
 * ~~~~~~ BONUS ~~~~~~ EXTRA CREDIT ~~~~~~ swap the values at grid[r1][c1]
 * and grid[r2][c2] you may use use an int temp as a temporary variable
 */
public static void gridSwap(int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
    int temp = grid[r1][c1];
    grid[r1][c1] = grid[r2][c2];
    grid[r2][c2] = temp;

}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.  What is the question?

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to do my first method with on;y one nestles loop and eliminate the first for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to do only the second loop

```
public static void gridTranspose() {
    if (gridIsSquare() == true) {
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length / 2 + 1; r++) {
            for (int c = r+1; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
                gridSwap(r, c, c, r);

            }
        }
    }
}
```